# How to pass value between kotlin class and java class in android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have a  class  one in java which implements AsyncTask and other is kotlin MainActivity.

Now I have a kotlin function with kotlin int as parameter in MainActivity.
 I have managed to call kotlin function in java class but unable to pass Java Integer,it shows compile time error. Is there any way to pass integer value?

Comment: What is the compile error and crash log?

Comment: I don't think using String is correct. Int should be able to be passed via an Integer object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your post, I guess that the compile error occurred due to using `int` instead of `Int` in Kotlin. Change your kotlin function to this

```
fun kotlinfun(i: Int){
    ...
}
```

and call normally in java class

```
int k=0;
obj.kotlinfun(k);
```

Answer (score 2):

Java using `int` instead `Integer`,

and in java to parse integer to string using `Integer.toString(k)`

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
int k=0;
obj.kotlinfun(String.valueOf(k));
```

- Convert using Integer.toString(int)
- Convert using String.valueOf(int)
- Convert using new Integer(int).toString()
- Convert using String.format()
- Convert using StringBuffer or StringBuilder.